# Can you keep using PasswordVault instances?

Tags: uwp, credential-manager

I'm working with a UWP app that makes use of the `PasswordVault` class to store things like AWS credentials securely in the Credential Locker.

In all the example code that I can find, any interaction with the locker leads to creating a new instance of a `PasswordVault`, even if it's in the same class.  For example, the [UWP documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/credential-locker) always creates a new instance before reading / writing values to the locker.  Even the [Credential Locker Sample code](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/PasswordVault-f01be74a) from Microsoft shows creating new instances of the `PasswordVault` over and over again before doing the actual work against the locker.

My question is - why?  Why does a developer need to create a new instance of the vault each time?  Is it necessary, or is it just a side-effect of "example code needs to be overly explicit all the time"?  Will there be negative side effects when just declaring a field for a `PasswordVault` instance, and re-using it for multiple interactions with the Credential Locker?  If it's not valid, can you point me at documentation about why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In all the example code that I can find, any interaction with the locker leads to creating a new instance of a PasswordVault, even if it's in the same class.

I don't know why the official code author writes like this, I guess he want make the code look easier to understand. For common use, you could create global `PasswordVault` instance to store retrieve or delete user credentials.